# Android SMS Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i want to have an activity that checks for incoming sms and when it contains some text it wil do something. 
but i don't know how to do this can anyone help me. I have searched on google but so far no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a broadcast receiver to get SMS messages like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsListener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />` in your manifest as well.

In your code you need

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String msg_from;
        if (bundle != null){
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks if found the probleme in my manifast file i had <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
it was the T

Answer (score 0):

You can act upon receiving a message, when you listen to this intent action

```
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
```

You can use a BroadcastReceiver to listen to this action